# bootstrap 3 datepicker rendering out of form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I've been working madly to figure out a well-working datepicker. I focused on Bootstrap 3 Datepicker but the problem is the control rendering badly ("goes off the model, corrupted when back to month or year view...)

code is as basic as you see in following example:

```
<script src="../../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="../../css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!--start date filed-->
               <div class="input-group date pull-right" data-provide="datepicker" >
                   <%: Html.TextBoxFor(mdl=>mdl.startDate,new {@class="form-control",  id="startDatePicker", @readonly="readonly", placeholder="Start Date"}) %>
                   <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="startDateBtn" ></span></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of first Date-->
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
  $('#startDatePicker').datepicker();
            })
        </script>
```

Comment: just make sure your css and js files are referenced correctly, you can do this with F-12 developer tool bar, available in most of web browsers.

Comment: nothign to do with dev tools. Everything is calling fine! @ijaz

Comment: if it was well working then try to remember what change you made last time? have to moved some files or what ? actually  <link href="../../css/bootstrap.css"> files sometimes goes out of reference. path like ../../css do not resolve correctly sometimes.

Comment: [Bootstrap datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) has no `datepicker` method. Are you sure that you are using this library?

Comment: The method works pretty good, the problem is only with the styling of the control.  @VincenzoC
Plz look at the design: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwWmO3Gn2fuTa1FQRTVXMWM1cms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Or this ugly style! https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwWmO3Gn2fuTRjhxTjFqY1VpbTA

Comment: Sorry for the ugly style, but I can't reproduce your issue by myself, because I'm not sure about your `bootstrap-datepicker.js` and `datepicker.css`. I've tried with files you can find [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/master/build/css) and everything is fine. Anyway, try lo import `bootstrap.css` before `datepicker.css`

Comment: you're definitely NOT using my picker. There's no `bootstrap-datepicker.js` or `datepicker.css` in my library. Unless you renamed them. as @VincenzoC pointed out, there's no method `datepicker` in my library either. You must be using something else

Comment: Hey @Eonasdan
I'm afraid that it's your control and yes. I just come across it somewhere on the internet and someone renamed it.
However, the problem was with a custom css file that cause the ugly shap and now it's perfect!